# Steam - accept trade offer in C#

Tags: c#, .net, steam, steambot

I'm trying to write steam trade bot in C#. I wrote decline method but I don't know how make accept method because Steam Web API don't have it. Next problem is steam mobile auth. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are fighting a lost battle, looking at how it is all laid out the steam API website these are the only states which a trade offer can be in:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td> <b>Name</b> 
    </td>
    <td> <b>Value</b> 
    </td>
    <td> <b>Comment</b>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>k_ETradeOfferConfirmationMethod_Invalid</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>Invalid
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>k_ETradeOfferConfirmationMethod_Email</td>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>An email was sent with details on how to confirm the trade offer
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>k_ETradeOfferConfirmationMethod_MobileApp</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>The trade offer may be confirmed via the mobile app
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The only way appears to be via the mobile app or confirming via email - see if the link in the emails are constructed in a predictable way, that won't help you with the mobileapp only ones but is a start...

Comment: Confirming via emails is nonsens because trades will be delayed by 7days probably. Confirming via mobile auth is possible because many sites have it.